# не понимаю как реализовать функцию для подсчета средней оценки за домашние задания по всем студентам в рамках конкретного курса Python

Tags: python, функции

Есть Класс студент

```
class Student:
def __init__(self, name, surname, gender):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    self.gender = gender
    self.finished_courses = []
    self.courses_in_progress = []
    self.grades = {}
    self.average_grade_course ={}
```

Создано 3 студента

```
student_1 = Student('Михаил', 'Кладько', 'Мужчина')
student_1.courses_in_progress += ['Python']
student_1.finished_courses += ['C++']
student_1.finished_courses += ['JavaScript']
student_1.finished_courses += ["Основы программирования"]

student_2 = Student('Александра', 'Паучкова', 'Женщина')
student_2.courses_in_progress += ['Python']
student_2.finished_courses += ['JavaScript']
student_2.finished_courses +=["Основы программирования"]

student_3 = Student('Кен', 'Каннеки', 'Мужчина')
student_3.courses_in_progress += ['JavaScript']
student_3.finished_courses += ['С++']
student_3.finished_courses +=["Основы программирования"]
```

у каждого студента свой средний балл по определённому курсу.
У student_1

```
average_grade_course = {'Python': [9.5], 'JavaScript': [7.0], 'C++': [9.5]}
```

у student_2

```
average_grade_course ={'Python': [7.5], 'JavaScript': [8.0]}
```

у student_3

```
average_grade_course ={'C++': [5.5], 'JavaScript': [8.0]}
```

Список всех студентов

```
student_list = [student_1, student_2, student_3]
```

Функция которую нужно реализовать

```
def average_grade_on_the_course(student_list, course_name):
```

нужно чтобы функция подсчитывала средний балл всех студентов по конкретному курсу и выводила:

```
Средняя оценка всех студентов по курсу Python: 8.5 
Средняя оценка всех студентов по курсу JavaScript: 7.67
Средняя оценка всех студентов по курсу С++: 7.5
```

Comment: Сорян, тут не делают "нужно реализовать" под заказ

Comment: В чём же сложность? В чём же вопрос? Делайте!

Comment: `average_grade_course = {'Python': [9.5],` - почему список? может быть несколько оценок по одному курсу?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ

```
def average_grade_on_the_course(persons, course):
    if not isinstance(persons, list):
        return "Not list"
    all_average_grade = []
    for person in persons:
        all_average_grade.extend(person.average_grade_course.get(course, []))
    if not all_average_grade:
        return "По такому курсу ни у кого нет оценок"
    return round(sum(all_average_grade) / len(all_average_grade), 2)
```